# Find expression in terms of $\theta$?

Tags: integration, problem-solving

So I've been given the following equation of motion of a particle:

$$\ddot{x} = g - {2gx\over a} \sin{\theta}$$

And have been told to:

> Find an expression in terms of $\space \theta \space$, for $\space {1\over 2}v^2 \space$, where $\space v \space$ is the speed of the particle.

My instincts told me to look at the following equality:

$$\ddot{x} = v{dv\over dx}= g - {2gx\over a} \sin{\theta}$$

Integrating both sides w.r.t. $\space x \space$ gives:

$$\int v \space dv = {1\over 2} v^2 = gx -{gx^2 \over a}\sin{\theta} + C$$

At $\space v=0, \space x=0 \space$ meaning $\space C=0$. So:

$${gx^2 \over a}\sin{\theta} = gx - {1\over 2} v^2$$

Then:

$$\sin{\theta} = {a\over x} - {a\over 2gx^2}v^2$$

Then finally:

$$\theta = \arcsin \huge( \normalsize{a\over x} - {a\over 2gx^2}v^2 \huge)$$

Is this what the question meant by **"Find an expression in terms of $\space \theta$"**?

Or is it asking something completely different?

Comment: It's asking for $\dfrac{v^2}{2}=f(\theta,x)$.

Comment: @NgChungTak - Ahhh alright. Thank you, the question just seemed to be worth more marks that simply making $\theta$ the subject haha.

Comment: @NgChungTak - And have I not just done that? Or is it something else?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you need to solve $v(t)$ completely.